# Download only instagram videos with instaloader

Tags: python, video, download, instagram, instaloader

This code is working for downloading all photos and videos

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile

L = Instaloader()
PROFILE = "username"
profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)

posts_sorted_by_likes = sorted(profile.get_posts(), key=lambda post: post.likes,reverse=True)

for post in posts_sorted_by_likes:
L.download_post(post, PROFILE)
```

Now i want to download only videos, But I can't. How can I filter this code for only videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Post` has an `is_video` [property](https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.Post.is_video)

```py
for post in posts_sorted_by_likes:
    if post.is_video:
        L.download_post(post, PROFILE)
```

Comment: It's great and useful, One little more question how about only photos?

Comment: @RasedulIslam from what I can see, if the post isn’t a video, it will be a photo. So you can just check `if not post.is_video`

Comment: It's not working, after giving `if not post.is_video` video is also downloading, Is there any other way i can download only photos?

Comment: You could try using `video_url`, which should be `None` for photos. For sidecar posts, you'll probably have to check that iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the '**is_video**' is not enough, so you can just delete the ones that don't have the .mp4 extension:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
        if not file.endswith(".mp4"):
            os.remove(path + file)
```

Comment: That's great it's working. I want to know how can I download only images without videos?

Comment: Maybe try: if not post.is_video: download . But again, I'm not sure it worked perfectly. You can always download everything and the clean it with the function above, but instead of 'endswith(".mp4") you use 'endswith(".jpg")